# How to set up this Moment Generating Function problem

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution, moment-generating-functions

The mgf of a certain random variable $X$ is $M_X(t)=e^{\frac12(e^t -1)}$. Find $\mathbb P(X>0)$.

-I know that $X\sim\mathrm{Poi}(1/2)$.

-I also know I solve this equation as $1-\mathbb P(X=0)$.

-I plugged $0$ to $t$ in the equation but my result was $0$, which I don't believe is true.

Please Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually $M_X(0)=1$, as is the case for all moment generating functions, but we cannot easily recover the probability distribution of $X$ from its moment generating function. Instead, recognizing that $X\sim\mathrm{Pois}(1/2)$, we find that
$$
\mathbb P(X>0) = 1-\mathbb P(X=0) = 1-e^{-1/2}.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense!